# Passing params to Asynchronous functions

Tags: c#, async-await

Sorry if this was asked before.
I have two almost identical functions sync and async:

```
    private static void runLong(int id)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("starting " + id );
        Thread.Sleep(myRandom.Next(200,1000));
        Console.WriteLine("-exiting " + id);
    }
    private static async Task runLongAsync(int id)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("starting " + id );
        await Task.Run(()=>Thread.Sleep(myRandom.Next(200,1000)));
        Console.WriteLine("-exiting " + id );
    }
```

I call them in a very similar way:

```
    public static void run()
    {
            run().Wait();
            runAsync().Wait();
    }
    private static async Task run()
    {
        List<Task> runningTasks = new List<Task>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            runningTasks.Add(Task.Run(() => runLong(i)));  
        }
        await Task.WhenAll(runningTasks);
    }
    private static async Task runAsync()
    {
        List<Task> runningTasks = new List<Task>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            runningTasks.Add(runLongAsync(i));   
        }
        await Task.WhenAll(runningTasks);
    }
```

However result is different:
Calling synchronous function asynchronously

- starting 5
- starting 5
- starting 5
- starting 5
- starting 5
- exiting 5
- exiting 5
- exiting 5
- exiting 5
- exiting 5

Calling asynchronous function:

- starting 0
- starting 1
- starting 2
- starting 3
- starting 4
- exiting 0
- exiting 3
- exiting 2
- exiting 1
- exiting 4

I.E. in first case parameters are overwritten but in the second- they are not. What's going on here?

Edit1: Yes I found a quick fix **int copy = i;** But I'd like to understand what's actually going on here and why these two functions behave differently.

Edit2: Articles referred by @Servy explain why *for* and *foreach* loops behave differently, in my case I have two *for* loops that behave differently

Comment: @Servy I'd like to understand what's going on here not just a quick fix **int copy = i;** like in the thread you suggested.

Comment: So then did you read the two linked articles with more detailed explanations of why this is behaving in this way?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand how it explains why in one case int is passed to the function by value and in other int is passed by reference

Comment: So, since you read those posts, you understand how closure semantics work for the snippet that uses a closure, and you just don't understand how calling a method normally without using closures passes values?  Or what is it that you don't understand?

Answer (score 0):

Captured variables. The `i` here is **not** per loop iteration, so it will pick up the current value *when it gets launched* - which will probably be `5`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    runningTasks.Add(Task.Run(() => runLong(i)));  
}
```

A workaround is to hoist the value inside the loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    var j = i;
    runningTasks.Add(Task.Run(() => runLong(j)));  
}
```

The important point here is that `j` is now scoped *inside* the loop, so the captured variable context is specific to that iteration.